# Error JQuery Function to Load Image Preview with Safari Browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari

I tried to create image preview function with JQuery. It's work with IE,Chrome,Firefox and Edge. but din't work with Safari.
This is my code:

```
<!-- JQuery -->
<script>
function bacaGambar(input) {
  if (input.files && input.files[0])
      {
        var reader = new FileReader();

         reader.onload = function (e) {
        $('#img_prev').attr('src', e.target.result);
         }

          reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
       }
    }
      $("#preview").change(function(){
       bacaGambar(this);
      });
</script>
```

Thank's.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace ids with classes in your html for Safari to work properly.
Modify `$("#img_prev")` to `$(".img_prev")` and `$("#preview")` to `$(".preview")`.

This advice is taken from the related question: [Jquery condition works in all browsers except safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23401899/jquery-condition-works-in-all-browsers-except-safari?rq=1).